# Seeding many-to-many databases in EFCore5 with ModelBuilder?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404629/seed-many-to-many-data-in-entity-framework) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640542/seeding-many-to-many-data) about seeding many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework. However, most of them are extremely old, and many-to-many behavior has [changed significantly in EFCore5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-efcore-5-0-rc1/#many-to-many). The [official docs recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) overriding `OnModelCreating` to implement `ModelBuilder.Entity<>.HasData()`.

However, with the new many-to-many behavior (without explicit mappings), I can find no clear path to seed the intermediate tables. To use the example of [this tutorial](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration), the `BookCategories` class is now implicit. Therefore, there is no path to explicitly declare the intermediate table values while seeding.

I've also tried simply assigning the arrays, e.g.,:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}  
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And then at seed time:

```
Book book = new Book() { BookId = 1, Title = "Brave New World" }

Category category = new Category() { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Dystopian" }

category.Books = new List<Book>() { book };
book.Categories = new List<Category>() { category };

modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(book);
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(category);
```

... but there are no entries created for `BookCategories` in the resulting migration. This was somewhat expected, as [this article suggests](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding) that one must explicitly seed the intermediate table. What I want is something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>().HasData(
  new BookCategory() { BookId = 1, CategoryId = 1 }
);
```

However, again, since there is no concrete class to describe `BookCategories` in EFCore5, the only way I can think of to seed the table is to manually edit the migration with additional `MigrationBuilder.InsertData`  commands, which rather defeats the purpose of seeding data via application code.

Comment: I used `modelBuilder.Entity("BookCategory").HasData(new {BookId = 1, CategoryId = 1});` and it's working for me

Answer (score 8):

> However, again, since there is no concrete class to describe `BookCategories` in EFCore5

Actually, as explained in the [What's new link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many), EF Core 5 allows you to have explicit join entity

```cs
public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public EBook Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

and configure the many-to-many relationship to use it

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasMany(left => left.Categories)
    .WithMany(right => right.Books)
    .UsingEntity<BookCategory>(
        right => right.HasOne(e => e.Category).WithMany(),
        left => left.HasOne(e => e.Book).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.BookId),
        join => join.ToTable("BookCategories")
    );
```

This way you can use all normal entity operations (query, change tracking, data model seeding etc.) with it

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>().HasData(
  new BookCategory() { BookId = 1, CategoryId = 1 }
);
```

still having the new many-to-many *skip navigations* mapping.

This is probably the simplest as well as the type-safe approach.

In case you thing it's too much, using the conventional join entity is also possible, but you need to know the [shared dictionary entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#property-bags) name, as well as the two [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) names. Which as you will see by convention might not be what you expect.

So, by convention the join entity (and table) name is

`{LeftEntityName}{RightEntityName}`

and the shadow property (and column) names are

- `{LeftEntityNavigationPropertyName}{RightEntityKeyName}`
- `{RightEntityNavigationPropertyName}{LeftEntityKeyName}`

The first question would be - which is the left/right entity? The answer is (not documented yet) - by convention the left entity is the one which name is less in alphabetical order. So with your example `Book` is left, `Category` is right, so the join entity and table name would be `BookCategory`.

It can be changed adding explicit

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasMany(left => left.Books)
    .WithMany(right => right.Categories);
```

and now it would be `CategoryBook`.

In both cases the shadow property (and column) names would be

- `CategoriesCategoryId`
- `BooksBookId`

So neither the table name, nor the property/column names are what you'd normally do.

And apart from the database table/column names, the entity and property names are important because you'd need them for entity operations, including the data seeding in question.

With that being said, even if you don't create explicit join entity, it's better to configure fluently the one created automatically by EF Core convention:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasMany(left => left.Categories)
    .WithMany(right => right.Books)
    .UsingEntity("BookCategory", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>),
        right => right.HasOne(typeof(Category)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("CategoryId"),
        left => left.HasOne(typeof(Book)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("BookId"),
        join => join.ToTable("BookCategories")
    );
```

Now you can use the entity name to access the `EntityTypeBuilder`

```
modelBuilder.Entity("BookCategories")
```

and you can seed it similar to [normal entities with shadow FK properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data) with anonymous type

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity("BookCategory").HasData(
  new { BookId = 1, CategoryId = 1 }
);
```

or for this specific property bag type entity, also with `Dictionary<string, object>` instances

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity("BookCategory").HasData(
  new Dictionary<string, object> { ["BookId"] = 1, ["CategoryId"] = 1 }
);
```

---

**Update:**

People seem to misinterpret the aforementioned "extra" steps and find them redundant and "too much", not needed.

I never said they are mandatory. If you know the conventional join entity and property names, go ahead directly to the last step and use anonymous type or `Dictionary<string, object>`.

I already explained the drawbacks of taking that route - loosing the C# type safety and using "magic" strings out of your control. You have to be smart enough to know the exact EF Core naming conventions and to realize that if you rename class `Book` to `EBook` the new join entity/table name will change from "BookCategory" to "CategoryEBook" as well as the order of the PK properties/columns, associated indexes etc.

Regarding the concrete problem with data seeding. If you really want to generalize it (OP attempt in their own answer), at least make it correctly by using the EF Core metadata system rather than reflection and assumptions. For instance, the following will extract these names from the EF Core metadata:

```cs
public static void HasJoinData<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this ModelBuilder modelBuilder,
    params (TFirst First, TSecond Second)[] data)
    where TFirst : class where TSecond : class
    => modelBuilder.HasJoinData(data.AsEnumerable());

public static void HasJoinData<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this ModelBuilder modelBuilder,
    IEnumerable<(TFirst First, TSecond Second)> data)
    where TFirst : class where TSecond : class
{
    var firstEntityType = modelBuilder.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TFirst));
    var secondEntityType = modelBuilder.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TSecond));
    var firstToSecond = firstEntityType.GetSkipNavigations()
        .Single(n => n.TargetEntityType == secondEntityType);
    var joinEntityType = firstToSecond.JoinEntityType;
    var firstProperty = firstToSecond.ForeignKey.Properties.Single();
    var secondProperty = firstToSecond.Inverse.ForeignKey.Properties.Single();
    var firstValueGetter = firstToSecond.ForeignKey.PrincipalKey.Properties.Single().GetGetter();
    var secondValueGetter = firstToSecond.Inverse.ForeignKey.PrincipalKey.Properties.Single().GetGetter();
    var seedData = data.Select(e => (object)new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        [firstProperty.Name] = firstValueGetter.GetClrValue(e.First),
        [secondProperty.Name] = secondValueGetter.GetClrValue(e.Second),
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity(joinEntityType.Name).HasData(seedData);
}
```

Also here you don't need to know which type is "left" and which is "right", neither requires special base class or interface. Just pass sequence of entity pairs and it will properly seed the conventional join entity, e.g. with OP example, both

```cs
modelBuilder.HasJoinData((book, category));
```

and

```cs
modelBuilder.HasJoinData((category, book));
```

would do.

Comment: Well, yes, I could explicitly define the mappings — thereby defeating the **entire** reason why I upgraded to EFCore5 in the first place (I have a **lot** of m2m tables, enough that this would double or even triple the number of models I need to write). I also disagree with your assessment that "it's better to configure fluently the one created automatically by EF Core convention." Why? You're basically arguing that the EFcore5 m2m feature is a "gocha" that shouldn't be used by developers. That said, you did solve my problem with the name-based access, so thank you!

Comment: Looks like the solution provided only works in RC1 if you **explicitly** set up the mappings, due to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22521 ... but RC2 was just released, so giving that a shot...

Comment: @ZaneClaes (1) The main benefit of the new m2m mapping is the skip navigation properties  to be used from normal crud. But the ability to map explicit class ((with straightforward boilerplate code) is improvement from EF6 and allows you to avoid some of the drawbacks of that model under some scenarios, w/o loosing the strongly typing.  (2) Explicit mapping is not strongly necessary, if you know the 3 mentioned names and EFC conventions (and the later do not change later and break the usage of your "magic" strings. You can use the names I showed you, but would you know them w/o this question?

Comment: If RC2 breaks it, it's just another proof that you shouldn't use unreleased software and also rely on (undocumented) EFC conventions.

Comment: Um, the issue I linked shows that your code does NOT work in RC1 without explicit mappings. I had the exact error message pasted there when I tried to use your code. It **only** works with RC2 (which I just confirmed after upgrading).

Comment: But in this particular case, luckily for us both solutions work in RC2 :)

Comment: Actually it works in RC1 as well, because that was what I tested before posting.

Comment: Really? If I add **just** the last block of code to my sample (none of the other blocks), it works on RC2 but not RC1.

Comment: As I said, I've tested in RC1 everything I wrote before posting it (I didn't know/there was no RC2 at that time). Now I did the same with RC2, and everything works as well. And the conventions are exactly the same. Note that w/o any other code, the last block should be use "BookCategory" as entity name and then the aforementioned ugly property names "BooksBookId" and "CategoriesCategoryId", which I was trying to avoid with explicit mapping to dictionary.

Comment: Well, there must be something different in our project setup somewhere. Because the issue I posted describes my RC1 problem exactly — it even shows code that looks exactly like yours — and it was acknowledged as a bug and fixed by the EFCore team in RC2.

Comment: The issue is reported for **daily** build - EF Core version: 6.0.0-alpha.1.20462.1, which is not the same as RC1. I'm not using daily builds. In general I don't use preview/RC (beta/alpha) software, but this case is exception for supporting the victims of MS Open Source nightmare :)

Comment: And yet, it was fixed in RC2: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/22652 — and the exact bug was present in `5.0.0-rc.1.20451.17`.

Comment: Hahah @ MS Open Source nightmare! No argument there. I just am trying to document what worked and what didn't. Again, I really appreciate the tip, and want to make sure this thread solves the issue for others :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Update (EF Core 5.0.2)

It's working well using the name of the associative table:

```
    builder.Entity("ContractDeclarationType").HasData(
        new { ContractsId = 1L, DeclarationTypesId = 1L },
        new { ContractsId = 1L, DeclarationTypesId = 2L },
        new { ContractsId = 1L, DeclarationTypesId = 3L });
```

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up whipping up a generic solution to this problem based upon the answer from Ivan (thanks!). I'm now able to seed all my M2M tables with this syntax:

```
// Add book1 and book2 to category1:
modelBuilder.HasM2MData(new [] { book1, book2 }, new [] { category1 });
```

This may not be fully robust, but it should work with conventional M2M mappings.

It makes some assumptions:

- `T1` & `T2` Inherit from some `ModelBase` that provides an `Id` property.
- `T1` & `T2` Have exactly one `ICollection<OtherType>` property.
- You know the correct order (which model is `T1` and which is `T2`) — this can be discovered by running the migration for the tables first and inspecting the migration.
- You're running EFCore5 RC2 or later (see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22521)).

```
public static void HasM2MData<T1, T2>
  (this ModelBuilder mb, T1[] t1s, T2[] t2s)
  where T1 : ModelBase where T2 : ModelBase
{
  string table = $"{typeof(T1).Name}{typeof(T2).Name}";
  PropertyInfo t1Prop = GetM2MProperty<T1, T2>();
  PropertyInfo t2Prop = GetM2MProperty<T2, T1>();
  string t1Key = $"{t1Prop.Name}Id";
  string t2Key = $"{t2Prop.Name}Id";
  foreach (T1 t1 in t1s) {
    foreach (T2 t2 in t2s) {
      mb.Entity(table).HasData(new Dictionary<string, object>() { [t2Key] = t1.Id, [t1Key] = t2.Id });
    }
  }
}

// Get a property on T1 which is assignable to type ICollection<T2>, representing the m2m relationship
private static PropertyInfo GetM2MProperty<T1, T2>() {
  Type assignableType = typeof(ICollection<T2>);
  List<PropertyInfo> props = typeof(T1).GetProperties()
                                       .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(assignableType))
                                       .ToList();
  if (props.Count() != 1) {
    throw new SystemException(
      $"Expected {typeof(T1)} to have exactly one column of type {assignableType}; got: {props.Count()}");
  }
  return props.First();
}
```

In the migration, we see something like:

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
table: "BookCategory",
columns: new[] { "BooksId", "CategoriesId" },
values: new object[,]
{
    { "book1", "category1" },
    { "book2", "category1" }
});
```